# How to exclude 1 OU from a script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

So I'm trying to get a PowerShell script that will search and disable all accounts that have been inactive for x amount of days. But I want it to skip over 1 OU where it doesn't search and disable any of the users in the OU. and then move all the disabled users to 1 single OU

This is the code I currently have. I am missing the exclude portion.

Use this code to disable accounts that have been inactive for X amount of days

```
Search-ADAccount -SearchBase “OU=example,DC=example,DC=com” -AccountInactive -TimeSpan (\[timespan\]0d) -UsersOnly | Set-ADUser -Enabled $false
```

Use this code to move users

```
Get-ADuser -SearchBase “OU=example,DC=example,DC=com” -filter {Enabled -eq $false} | Move-ADObject -TargetPath “OU=Computers,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com”
```

I'm not 100% sure how to use the exclude command and i tried googling and finding other scripts that could potentially work, but nothing has so far

Comment: Please remember to only use the [tag:powershell] tag that correspond with your actual version. Regarding your question, how long does it take to run `Search-ADAccount` ?

Comment: Why do you need to skip a particular OU?

Comment: it has users that no matter how long they are inactive to never be disabled or deleted

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon to run the current script where it search-ADAccount for all OU folders it takes about a second to run, disable, and move users to the folder i have pathed it too. now i just need to find a way to edit this script to skip 1 OU folder

Comment: Why not use an OU that's not within the scope of your search? Then there's no need to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could do all the process in a single pipeline, however I have not personally tested it. This is not an efficient method to exclude a specific Organizational Unit however, as you have mentioned in comments, this process takes only seconds for you so it should be Ok.

```
$ouToExclude = 'OU=example123,DC=example,DC=com'

Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "OU=example,DC=example,DC=com" -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]0d) -UsersOnly |
    Group-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -replace '^CN=.*(?=OU=)' } |
    Where-Object Name -NE $ouToExclude | ForEach-Object Group |
    Set-ADUser -Enabled $false -PassThru |
    Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Computers,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com"
```

1. Search for all inactive user objects
2. Group the users by their parent OU. This is done with `Group-Object` and a [calculated expression script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-group-integers-by-odds-and-evens)
3. Filter the results where the parent OU **is not equal** to the `$ouToExclude`
4. Pass the group of objects to `Set-ADUser` to disable them and then with `-PassThru` we can pass those disabled objects to `Move-ADObject`

Comment: with only the one added change $ouToExclude = 'OU=skip,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com' it still pulls the users from the OU skip and disable and moves them

Comment: @Mohamad try changing `-NE` to `-NotMatch`

Comment: tried that and it still pulls from all OU's

Comment: @Mohamad no idea then probably the OU to exclude you're using is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the real Distinguished names of the OU's, I believe it is better to use the non-regex `-like` operator here to test if a user is in (sub) OU defined in the $exclude variable or not.

Try

```
$searchBase  = "OU=example,DC=example,DC=com"                   # DN of the OU to search in
$exclude     = 'OU=example123,DC=example,DC=com'                # DN of the OU to exclude
$destination = 'OU=InactiveUsers,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com'  # DN of the OU to move inactive users to

Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $searchBase -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]0d) -UsersOnly |
Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*$exclude"} |
ForEach-Object { 
    $_ | Set-ADUser -Enabled $false
    $_ | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $destination
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$excludedOU = ‘OU=skip,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com’ 
Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "OU=example,DC=example,DC=com" -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]0d) -UsersOnly | 
Group-Object { $_.DistinguishedName -replace '^CN=.*(?=OU=)' } | Get-ADuser -Filter * | ? { $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $excludedOU -and $_.DistinguishedName -notmatch ‘CN=Admin,OU=Users,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com’}| 
Set-ADUser -Enabled $false -PassThru | 
Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=Computers,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com"
```